# header_image not working after site copy

Tags: clone-site, header-image

I did a copy of a production site to a development site, but the header_image doesn't work after the copy.

The copy was done by doing a copy&replace of the host in the db dump file. Everything seems to work except that I now only get the default custom header image and not the one that was earlier configured for each site.

I have looked into debugging this issue, but it gets complicated. Has anyone experienced this issue and know how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not recommended to make a simple search&replace in the dump file when moving to another host, because of the presence of serialized data in some database fields (usually options fields of core and plugins).

I would recommend to use one of the following migration plugins/scripts to handle the data conversion when moving Wordpress:

1. [Wordpress Move](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-move/) (WP plugin)
2. [Search and replace for Wordpress](http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) (PHP script)

Comment: WPMS seems to fail with wrong db so I had to use option 2. Nice intuitive script and it worked very well. I wasn't aware of the serialization issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Configured - Does it mean you can set a header image through theme options? If yes, then you can try re-uploading it. Also, install the plugin `search and replace` and search through it for the old site's home URL and replace it with the new one. It could be an issue with the URLs.